# How to organize data persistence in icefaces project?

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, icefaces

What should be relation between Hibernate/JPA entities - backing beans and where should I write and read data from db in web project based on icefaces components?

Answer (score 0):

You have persistence layer (JPA/Hibernate) and presentation layer (icefaces) and what you are missing here the service layer (or business layer); I think Spring framework can fill this layer.